# My mapFragment isn't reappear when I setVisibility

Tags: android, menuitem

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
Case R.id.MapID:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Showing Google MAP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(mapFragment.isHidden()){
                mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            return true;}}
```

So my Google map shows in screen, but when I press on Map in Menu it disappears, but when I re-click on map again it doesn't show up.How do i set it to visible again?

Comment: post your full code

Comment: please check your **if statement**

Comment: are you getting toast for "Showing Google MAP" ? because your spell for case is wrong. so make it in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me hope it will work for you

```
if(mapFragment.isVisible()){
 mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
   mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me 'cannnot resolve method getVisibility()' error

Comment: use mapFragment.isShown()

Comment: please post your complete code or you can try mapFragment.isVisible()

Comment: isVisible(), it does not hide, map just stays there!

Comment: mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE); use it for hide